# Error reporting is not working properly

Tags: php

i have a php  page

While running it will display following messages

```
Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in test_step2.php on line 64

Warning: mysql_select_db() [function.mysql-select-db]: A link to the server could not be established in test_step2.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined variable: exists in test_step2.php on line 341
```

**I want to avoid the displaying of these messages**

I have no access to *php.ini* file

i have tried the following code one by one to avoid the displaying of these messages

- error_reporting(0)
- ini_set('display_errors',0);
- error_reporting(E_NONE);

but no use

Can any one help me to avoid the display of these messages

Comment: Why do you try to connect to the database if you don't need it? What's the `test_step2.php` file for?

Comment: Do you have access to your .htaccess file?

Comment: @Juhuna Who said anything about whether he needs the database or not. This question is about disabling error output.

Comment: E_NONE does not exist (as far as I know) and ini_set('display_errors', ... expects a *string* as of PHP 5.2.4

Comment: @JohnCartwright I assume that if the notices are the only problem, the script works. And if it works without a database connection, wouldn't the simplest solution be to just delete the lines that throw the notices?

Comment: The error output is there for a reason.  Disabling it is the *wrong* way to fix this problem.  If you want to use the database, check the credentials, if you don't, remove those lines.  PHP gives these notices to help you, ignoring them will only lead to bigger problems in the future, trust me.  Fix your code, don't ignore it.

Comment: You are making assumptions that are a) outside the scope of the question b) impossible to know whether it is correct or not. Best to keep comments/answers on topic with the question itself.

Comment: @Rocket Showing error output to the clients is definitely the wrong thing to do. I agree you should not "disable" output reporting, just the "reporting".

Comment: @JohnCartwright: This is on topic.  We *could* tell him how to disable error messages, but the "more correct" solution here is to fix the errors.  We're giving alternative advice, not going off topic.  Also, who said anything about showing the errors to the client.  I'd hope a capable PHP dev would fix his errors *before* the client ever sees the page.

Comment: @Rocket Of course he should fix the errors. But that is not what his question is about, now is it? Imagine a situation where your database goes down. You should handle the errors gracefully, not dump PHP errors and a stack-trace to the client.

Comment: @JohnCartwright: "handle the errors gracefully", I agree, but disabling errors isn't handling errors gracefully.  He needs to check the DB, and if it's down display a "sorry website down" or something on the page.  Also, I'm not totally sure what the question is about.  Disabling errors is a bad idea, so let's tell the OP a better solution then just what he thinks he's looking for.

Comment: Ok, I can see what you're aiming at and you're making a good point, but everything points to this being the *normal situation* (e.g. the error would not be "access denied" if the database is down) and the OP wants to just *suppress* the messages, not fix them.

Comment: @Juhana: As a PHP dev, I think suppressing errors is a bad idea.  Though I guess without knowing what the OP is trying to do (in the big picture I mean), I can't really give other advice.

Comment: @Rocket Right, sorry, my comment was meant for John...

Comment: @Everyone I never said to disable the errors themselves. I simply said to disable the error reporting to the client. The client should never receive any errors from PHP. You should catch your errors and display a HTTP 500 or custom error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the errors here is probably a bad idea.  Instead of hiding the messages, you should try to fix them.  PHP gives notices for a reason, not fixing them could lead to bigger issues in the future.

You should check your database credentials to fix the connection errors, not just ignore the errors.  Don't you need the database in your program?  Why else would you connect to it?  If you don't need the database, then remove those lines from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including other files that are changing your error settings? If not try

```
@mysql_select_db(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

edit `.htaccess` file

```
php_value error_reporting 0
php_flag display_errors Off
```

or contact server administrator...